# Cordova / iOS8 Push Notifications

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add push notifications to my Ionic/Cordova iOS8 app. I already have this working in Android, but am having some difficulty with iOS (go figure). The first thing I did was to install the plugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). Then I manually copied the PushNotification.js file into the platforms/ios/www/plugins/www folder. Then I made a separate controller to see if the plugin would work. There is no logging in the XCode console (I do have the console logging plugin installed and working).

```
.controller('PushCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$cordovaPush', 'AuthService', 'UserFactory', function($scope, $location, $cordovaPush, AuthService, UserFactory) {
    if (typeof $cordovaPush !== 'undefined' && typeof device !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(device.platform);
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            var config = {
                senderID: GCMsenderID
            };
        } else {
            var config = {
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true",
                "alert": "true"
            }
        }
        $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function(result) {
            console.log("Push Notification Result: " + result);
            UserFactory.gcm('register', result.deviceToken);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Unable to device token from Google Cloud Messaging');
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Device is undefined?');
    }
}])
```

All that the gcm method in the UserFactory does is post the value to the server. I made sure the  plugin is installed correctly and I followed Apple's tutorials on creating the SSL certificates exactly. I am at a standstill and not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Under the cordova push plugin 2.4,  the device token is stored in result instead of result.devicetoken for iOS.

Try changing to this and see if it works:

```
UserFactory.gcm('register', result);
```